# How do I handle permission denied in xamarin forms iOS devices

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I am encountering a "xamarin.essentials.permission exception message=locationwheninuse permission was not granted: denied" and I have no idea how to handle this.

I am using xam.plugin.geolocator and here is my plist

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
  <array>
    <string>location</string>
  </array>
  <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
  <string>LaunchScreen</string>
  <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
  <string>This app needs access to location when open.</string>
  <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
  <string>This app needs access to location when in the background.</string>
  <key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
  <string>This app needs access to location when open and in the background.</string>
  <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
  <array>
    <string>location</string>
  </array>
```

while here is my appdelegate

```
public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
    {
        //
        // This method is invoked when the application has loaded and is ready to run. In this 
        // method you should instantiate the window, load the UI into it and then make the window
        // visible.
        //
        // You have 17 seconds to return from this method, or iOS will terminate your application.
        //
        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init();

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();

            Syncfusion.Licensing.SyncfusionLicenseProvider.RegisterLicense(AppSetting.SyncfusionLicense);
            Syncfusion.XForms.iOS.TextInputLayout.SfTextInputLayoutRenderer.Init();
            SfCalendarRenderer.Init();
            new SfCarouselRenderer();
            Xamarin.FormsMaps.Init();
            ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.iOS.Platform.Init();

            LoadApplication(new App(new iOSInitializer()));

            UITabBar.Appearance.SelectedImageTintColor = UIColor.Black;
            UITabBar.Appearance.TintColor = UIColor.Gray;
            UITabBar.Appearance.BarTintColor = UIColor.White;

            return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
        }
    }
```

to replicate, I just deployed the app in a device.  Once opened, it will ask you for a permission.  Click "Don't Allow".

Any insights?

TIA.

Comment: You are NOT showing the permission code in your question, but you need to **check** the permissions first before requesting them so you can skip the request (and thus the `PermissionException`) if the user has already denied them : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/permissions?tabs=ios#checking-permissions

Comment: I tried to use that in my mainpage viewmodel, on my mainpage code behind and other pages as well as on the app.cs.  But i don't where else to place it.

Comment: Why don't you just check the Permissions status and show them a dialog box saying that they can't login to the app unless they have already accepted all permissions? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/permissions?tabs=android#checking-permissions And then request the permission or else cancel sign in?

Comment: Hi Saamer, I did that as well.  It is triggered on the first launch after its installed on the device.

Comment: @JohnMombay Hi, do you mean the permission dialog always show "not allow"?

Comment: Yes Junior Jiang.  When I tap on Not Allow, it crashes.

Comment: @JohnMombay Okey, you can [check the permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/permissions?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android#checking-permissions) before using code to invoke their methods to have a try.